# Saving all browser's (any) AJAX activity to disk

Tags: ajax, browser

I'm developing web application that uses AJAX a lot. It sends several AJAX requests to server per second and update page's content based on the request result.

Is there a way I can save all responses sent from server to browser using AJAX to disc in order to analyze it later?

It is not good to make 'alert' after each request because there are too many requests and I'll not be able to see if the browser works well in this case.

I've tried to use firebug or greasemonkey for Firefox but I failed to save data to disk using them.

Is there any solution for it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)?

It's an application which monitors all http traffic. It's good, and it's free.